# Is this conclusion true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose we have 4 sets, namely, $A,B,C$ and $D$, such that the following holds:

\begin{align}
|A\cup B| &\leq |A\cup C| \\
|C\cup D| &\leq |B\cup D| \\
A\cap B &= \emptyset \\
C\cap D &= \emptyset
\end{align}

I need to take conclusions from these sets.

Knowing that $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$ and $A\cap B = \emptyset$, we can show that $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|$ and $|C\cup D|=|C|+|D|$. The first equation then gets transformed into

\begin{align}
|A|+|B| &\leq |A\cup C| = |A|+|C|-|A\cap C| \\
|B|+|A\cap C| &\leq |C|
\end{align}

and the second one into

\begin{align}
|C|+|D|&\leq|B\cup D|=|B|+|D|-|B\cap D| \\
|C|+|B\cap D| &\leq |B|
\end{align}

by squeeze theorem we can show that $|B|=|C|$ combining the equations, and it follows from there that $|A\cap C|=|B\cap D|=0$. Is this a valid conclusion? I feel like it's not, because if $A=C=\{x\mid x\text{ is even}\}\subset\mathbb{N}$ and $B=D=\{x\mid x\text{ is odd}\}\subset\mathbb{N}$, then the condition holds, but the conclusion is not true. Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: You are using an inclusion-exclusion principle which is valid only for finite sets. But your example uses infinite sets.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you wish to set A=C={x|x is even} or so about B and D you must be careful because those sets are of infinite numbers and generally everywhere in math anything may happen at infinity. This is not true for the sets you exemplified because $Natural-numbers$ infinity is still different with that of $Even-numbers$.
If there is still a bit of ambiguity, set A=C={$2k|1\le k\le n$} and B=D={$2k-1|1\le k\le n$} and you see that it doesn't satisfy the problem conditions.